# Querying RDF File in RDFDOTNET

Tags: rdf

I am querying rdf file using rdfdotnet library

Here is my code

```
//Define your Graph here - it may be better to use a QueryableGraph if you plan
//on making lots of Queries against this Graph as that is marginally more performant
IGraph g = new Graph();

//Load some data into your Graph using the LoadFromFile() extension method
g.LoadFromFile("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/current/Semantic/test.rdf");

//Use the extension method ExecuteQuery() to make the query against the Graph
try
{
    String q = " Prefix u:<http://localhost:49682/Semantic/test.rdf> SELECT * WHERE {?x1 u:age ?x2}";
        Object results = g.ExecuteQuery(q);

        if (results is SparqlResultSet)
        {
            //SELECT/ASK queries give a SparqlResultSet
            SparqlResultSet rset = (SparqlResultSet)results;
            foreach (SparqlResult r in rset)
            {
                //Do whatever you want with each Result
            }
        }
        else if (results is IGraph)
        {
            //CONSTRUCT/DESCRIBE queries give a IGraph
            IGraph resGraph = (IGraph)results;
            foreach (Triple t in resGraph.Triples)
            {
                //Do whatever you want with each Triple
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //If you don't get a SparqlResutlSet or IGraph something went wrong 
            //but didn't throw an exception so you should handle it here
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
        }
    }
    catch (VDS.RDF.Query.RdfQueryException queryEx)
    {
        //There was an error executing the query so handle it here
        Console.WriteLine(queryEx.Message);
    }
```

It give an error when I am executing my query

[UriToken at Line 1 Column 10 to Line 1 Column 52] Expected a Prefix Token to follow the PREFIX Verb in a Query

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the library are you using?

Older versions had a bug where there had to be a space between the prefix - in your case `u:` - and the namespace URI - in your case `<http://localhost:49682/Semantic/test.rdf>`

If you use the latest version of the library (0.5.1) you will no longer have this issue

**Edit**

This was fixes in Version 0.5.0 (see issue [CORE-88](http://dotnetrdf.org/tracker/Issues/IssueDetail.aspx?id=88)) so you are at least two versions behind at the time of writing if you are seeing this error, as I already answered upgrading should solve the issue.